# How can I prevent many sidekiq jobs from exceeding the API calls limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, synchronization, sidekiq, distributed-system

I am working on an Ruby On Rails application. We have many sidekiq workers that can process multiple jobs at a time. Each job will make calls to the Shopify API, the calls limit set by Shopify is `2 calls per second`. I want to synchronize that, so that only two jobs can call the API in a given second. 
The way I'm doing that right now, is like this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class Synchronizer

  attr_reader :shop_id, :queue_name, :limit, :wait_time

  def initialize(shop_id:, queue_name:, limit: nil, wait_time: 1)
    @shop_id = shop_id
    @queue_name = queue_name.to_s
    @limit = limit
    @wait_time = wait_time
  end

  # This method should be called for each api call
  def synchronize_api_call
    raise "a block is required." unless block_given?
    get_api_call
    time_to_wait = calculate_time_to_wait
    sleep(time_to_wait) unless Rails.env.test? || time_to_wait.zero?
    yield
  ensure
    return_api_call
  end

  def set_api_calls
    redis.del(api_calls_list)
    redis.rpush(api_calls_list, calls_list)
  end

  private

  def get_api_call
    logger.log_message(synchronizer: 'Waiting for api call', color: :yellow)
    @api_call_timestamp = redis.brpop(api_calls_list)[1].to_i
    logger.log_message(synchronizer: 'Got api call.', color: :yellow)
  end

  def return_api_call
    redis_timestamp = redis.time[0]
    redis.rpush(api_calls_list, redis_timestamp)
  ensure
    redis.ltrim(api_calls_list, 0, limit - 1)
  end

  def last_call_timestamp
    @api_call_timestamp
  end

  def calculate_time_to_wait
    current_time = redis.time[0]
    time_passed = current_time - last_call_timestamp.to_i
    time_to_wait = wait_time - time_passed
    time_to_wait > 0 ? time_to_wait : 0
  end

  def reset_api_calls
    redis.multi do |r|
      r.del(api_calls_list)
    end
  end

  def calls_list
    redis_timestamp = redis.time[0]
    limit.times.map do |i|
      redis_timestamp
    end
  end

  def api_calls_list
    @api_calls_list ||= "api-calls:shop:#{shop_id}:list"
  end

  def redis
    Thread.current[:redis] ||= Redis.new(db: $redis_db_number)
  end

end
```

the way I use it is like this

```
synchronizer = Synchronizer.new(shop_id: shop_id, queue_name: 'shopify_queue', limit: 2, wait_time: 1)
# this is called once the process started, i.e. it's not called by the jobs themselves but by the App from where the process is kicked off.
syncrhonizer.set_api_calls # this will populate the api_calls_list with 2 timestamps, those timestamps will be used to know when the last api call has been sent.
```

then when a job wants to make a call

```
syncrhonizer.synchronize_api_call do
   # make the call  
end
```

#### The problem

The problem with this is that if for some reason a job `fails to return to the api_calls_list the api_call it took`, that will make that job and the other jobs stuck for ever, or until we notice that and `we call set_api_calls` again. That problem won't affect that particular shop only, but also the other shops as well, because the sidekiq workers are shared between all the shops using our app.  It happen sometimes that we don't notice that until a user calls us, and we find that it was stuck for many hours while it should be finished in a few minutes.

#### The Question

I just realised lately that Redis is not the best tool for shared locking. So I am asking, `Is there any other good tool for this job??` If not in the Ruby world, I'd like to learn from others as well. I'm interested in the techniques as well as the tools. So every bit helps.

Comment: Sidekiq Enterprise has a rate limiting API, exactly designed to solve this problem. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Rate-Limiting

Answer (score 1):

You may want to restructure your code and create a micro-service to process the API calls, which will use a local locking mechanism and force your workers to wait on the socket. It comes with the added complexity of maintaining the micro-service. But if you're in a hurry then Ent-Rate-Limiting looks cool too.